# How to set password to workbook in sheetjs javascript

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

In my project and using Sheetjs for converting html table to excel sheet it's working fine. But I need to set password for workbook and then send Excel file to server using Ajax. But at server side I am getting file but it's without password

For eg:-
formData.append('Excel',new File([wbout],'Data.xls')):

I want to add password to file and then append it to formData